# Alias and functions

Tags: bash, alias, function

From the bash manual

> The rules concerning the definition and use of aliases are somewhat
>   confusing. Bash always reads at least one complete line of input
>   before executing any of the commands on that line. Aliases are
>   expanded when a command is read, not when it is executed. Therefore,
>   an alias definition appearing on the same line as another command does
>   not take effect until the next line of input is read. The commands
>   following the alias definition on that line are not affected by the
>   new alias. This behavior is also an issue when functions are executed.
>   **Aliases are expanded when a function definition is read, not when the function is executed**, because a function definition is itself a
>   compound command. As a consequence,
>   **aliases defined in a function are not available until after that function is executed**. To be safe, always put alias definitions on a
>   separate line, and do not use alias in compound commands.

The two sentences "Aliases are expanded when a function definition is read, not when the function is executed" and "aliases defined in a function are not available until after that function is executed" seem to be contrary to each other.

Can you explain what they mean respectively?

Comment: Good question! I leaned something new today. I learned 2 things, actually: 1) this info about alias expansion at the time the function def is read, and 2) that I should really read the bash manual carefully (which I thought I already did, but apparently didn't ^^ )

Comment: The main question is, should anyone use aliases in noninteractive mode? That's what functions are for, and aliases just make scripting more error-prone. I've actually never needed the info above, because I only ever encountered aliases in `.bashrc` files at the very top.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

1. Aliases are expanded when a function definition is read,
   not when the function is executed …

   ```
   $ echo "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog." > myfile
    
   $ alias myalias=cat
    
   $ myfunc() {
   >     myalias myfile
   > }
    
   $ myfunc
   The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
    
   $ alias myalias="ls -l"
    
   $ myalias myfile
   -rw-r--r-- 1 myusername mygroup 45 Dec 13 07:07 myfile
    
   $ myfunc
   The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
   ```

   Even though `myfunc` was defined to call `myalias`,
   and I’ve redefined `myalias`,
   `myfunc` still executes the original definition of `myalias`. 
   Because the alias was *expanded* when the function was defined. 
   In fact, the shell no longer remembers that `myfunc` calls `myalias`;
   it knows only that `myfunc` calls `cat`:

   ```
   $ type myfunc
   myfunc is a function
   myfunc ()
   {
   cat myfile
   }
   ```
2. … aliases defined in a function are not available
   until after that function is executed.

   ```
   $ echo "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog." > myfile
    
   $ myfunc() {
   >     alias myalias=cat
   > }
    
   $ myalias myfile
   -bash: myalias: command not found
    
   $ myfunc
    
   $ myalias myfile
   The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
   ```

   The `myalias` alias isn’t available
   until the `myfunc` function has been executed. 
   (I believe it would be rather odd
   if defining the function that defines the alias
   was enough to cause the alias to be defined.)

Comment: +1, good answer. An important "corollary" to this is that if one intends to define functions and aliases in a script, better put the aliases definition before the functions definitions! (obvious, now, given the answer, but I didn't knew this).

Comment: Thanks. I think an underlying issue is the difference between running the definition of a function and calling a function. Specifically, what shell operations are performed during running the definition of a function and during calling the function respectively? Is there any shell operations which are performed during both running the definition of a function and calling the function, or do running the definition of a function and calling the function perform non-overlapping set of shell operations?

Comment: Well, it’s a little like the difference between building a car and driving a car.  Or buying a sandwich and eating a sandwich.  I have provided a more detailed answer to [your other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/383800/80216 "Which of the following shell operations are performed inside the function body when running a function definition and when calling a function?").

Comment: Thanks. After rereading the quote   from the bash manual and your reply, I am confused about the meaning of executing a function. Does it mean executing the definition of a function, or calling a function? See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/384209/674

Answer (score 3):

**I need the answer that is stated by the first sentence when I try below snippet in my `.bashrc`**.

```
alias ls='\ls -F --color=auto --show-control-chars'
alias ll='ls -ahl'
function lf_macro() {
    local CMD=${1:-ls} DIR=${2:-.};
    $CMD $(find $DIR -maxdepth 1 -type f);
}
function lf() { lf_macro ll "$1"; }
function lsf() { lf_macro ls "$1"; }     # list all file, no directories
```

after `unalias -a; source ~/.bashrc`, I try to execute `lf` and `lsf`,

```
$ lf
-bash: ll: command not found

$ lsf
./file1 ./file2 ./script.sh ...     # no color, no control-chars

$ ls $(find -maxdepth 1 -type f)
./file1 ./file2 ./script.sh* ...
```

**it seems clearly that aliases are expanded at function definition, not function execution, since**:

- when I execute `lf`, the error `-bash: ll: command not found`, and
- when I execute `lsf`, `/usr/bin/ls` is used, not the alias form, no color
  highlight, and no control chars after executable file.

Answer (score -4):

You can say (for example)

alias mvn="mvn -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true $@"

IE you can repeat the name of the alias within the definition, but you
can't do that with a function; bash will just stack overflow and die.

There's probably a way around this but IDK what it is.

Comment: Note that `$@` would be expanded at the time the alias is defined as it's in double quotes. However, I'm assuming you are trying to use `$@` as "the arguments of the alias". An alias does not take arguments, it just replaces the command with a string, and any further arguments are just tucked on to the end of the resulting command line. Regarding your issue with calling `mvn` from within a function called `mvn`, just use `command mvn` to call the "real" `mvn` in your function (this would avoid calling the function recursively).

Comment: Also note that you are not actually answering the question that Tim posed.